# grails run-app throws NoClassDefFoundError for domain class

Tags: grails, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to run a Grails app inherited from another developer. It has just one domain class, which we'll call `foopackage.DomainObject`. When I compile it, a `.class` file turns up in `target/classes` just as I'd expect. However, when I try `grails run-app`, I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method 
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
initialize class foopackage.DomainObject
```

At first I thought this might be because `DomainObject` was trying to talk to a nonexistent database in a broken static initializer, so I reduced it down to just

```
package foopackage

class DomainObject {}
```

And I still get the same error. Maybe there's some underlying configuration/GORM problem, but it's not showing up with `--stacktrace`. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, it turns out it was the static initializer after all, and when I thought I'd ruled that out I was editing the wrong file.